# shell script to extract between characters

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk

I would like to extract a user name from the file between the keywords "/" and "NET" like below. How can I do so with programs like `awk`, `sed` or `cut`.

from:

```
audit: command=true   rsa1/abc.domain.net@xyz.DOMAIN.NET running
audit: command=true   user2/xyz.domain.net@xyz.DOMAIN.NET executing
```

to:

```
audit: command=true   rsa1 running
audit: command=true   user2 executing
```

Comment: `sed -e 's#/.* ##'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
< inputfile sed 's/\/.*NET//' > outputfile
```

Using `sed` in-place:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\/.*NET//' inputfile
```

**Command #1 breakdown**:

- `< inputfile`: redirects the content of `inputfile` to `sed`'s `stdin`
- `> outputfile`: redirects the content of `sed`'s `stdout` to `outputfile`

**Command #2 breakdown**:

- `-i.bak`: Forces `sed` to create an `inputfile.bak` backup file and to edit `inputfile` in-place
- `inputfile`: Forces `sed` to read the input from `inputfile`

**Regex breakdown**:

- `s`: asserts to perform a substitution
- `/`: starts the search pattern
- `\/`: matches a `/` character
- `.*NET`: matches any number of any character up to the end of a `NET` string
- `/`: stops the search pattern / starts the replace pattern
- `/`: stops the replace pattern

Sample output:

```bsh
~/tmp$ cat inputfile
audit: command=true   rsa1/abc.domain.net@xyz.DOMAIN.NET running
audit: command=true   user2/xyz.domain.net@xyz.DOMAIN.NET executing
~/tmp$ < inputfile sed 's/\/.*NET//' > outputfile
~/tmp$ cat outputfile 
audit: command=true   rsa1 running
audit: command=true   user2 executing
~/tmp$ sed -i.bak 's/\/.*NET//' inputfile
~/tmp$ cat inputfile.bak
audit: command=true   rsa1/abc.domain.net@xyz.DOMAIN.NET running
audit: command=true   user2/xyz.domain.net@xyz.DOMAIN.NET executing
~/tmp$ cat inputfile
audit: command=true   rsa1 running
audit: command=true   user2 executing
~/tmp$
```

Comment: I like the way you explain these.

Answer (score 3):

You can try also with `awk`:

```
awk '{ split($3, a, "/"); $3 = a[1]; } 1' file
```